# Backbone.js - Filtering a large JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I am building a Backbone application to display a list of contacts. I have followed tutorials online, and followed the model of loading the entire list of contacts into memory in one go, filtering results as the user enters values into a textbox. There are about 10 - 12 attributes of each contact and the data needs to be filtered by three of them. For example: name, location and zipcode

The problem is when the data set gets large. If I run the application with a JSON file containing 5000 users it becomes prohibitively slow. What techniques can I employ to get around the problem? Do I need to sort the JSON data? Anything else I can do?

I hope this question is not too vague and that I have explained the situation sufficiently.

Comment: Paging is the best way to go.. You should always and should avoid processing on the Front-end.. All the heavy lifting should be taken care by the BE..

Comment: Using pagination? I want a user to type in a name, or even the begining of a name eg. "Bill" and every Bill in the dataset should load into the DOM, likewise with locations or zipcodes.

Comment: Pass in extra query Params to your collection url before you fetch your collection .. Something in these line `urlstring?name=bi&zip=67&loc=par`  . Then query and return the requested data that satisfies these condition

Comment: Cool, thanks. I am new to building production apps, as opposed to the ones you find in online tutorials or books. Thanks again.